# Delete crossed and go to line below when clicking button

Tags: javascript, html, css

1. Every time you click on "Add grade" button, I want the next things that will appear to be in the line below that one.
2. And when I click on the button "-", I want everything in that line to be erased.

[delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7des.jpg)
[nextline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpfUp.jpg)
Just try the code below and you'll see what I'm talking about.

````
input[type="number"]{
    color : transparent;
    text-shadow : 0 0 0 #000;
}
input[type="number"]:focus{
    outline : none;
}
</style>
<button type="button" id="dugme1" onclick="javascript:dodajocenu();"> Add grade</button>
<br><br>
<div id="stranica">
</div>

<script>
  var ocena = 0;

  function removeElement(obrisi) {
    var dugme = obrisi.target;
    var input = dugme.previousSibling;
    var brisi = dugme.parentElement;
    brisi.removeChild(dugme);
    brisi.removeChild(input);
  }

  function dodajocenu() {
    ocena++;

    //create textbox
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = "number";
    input.setAttribute("max",5);
    input.setAttribute("min",1);

var myParent = document.body;

//Create array of options to be added
var array = ["Volvo","Saab","Mercades","Audi"];

//Create and append select list
var selectList = document.createElement('select');
selectList.id = "mySelect";
myParent.appendChild(selectList);

//Create and append the options
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = array[i];
    option.text = array[i];
    selectList.appendChild(option);
}   

    //create remove button
    var remove = document.createElement('button');
    remove.onclick = function(obrisiocenu) {
      removeElement(obrisiocenu);
    }
    remove.setAttribute("type", "dugme");
    remove.innerHTML = "-";

    stranica.appendChild(input);
    stranica.appendChild(selectList);
    stranica.appendChild(remove);

  }

</script>```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run the following code, let me know if this is what you want to do.

```js
var ocena = 0;

var stranica = document.querySelector("#stranica")

function removeElement(obrisi) {
  var dugme = obrisi.target;
  stranica.removeChild(dugme.parentElement)
}

function dodajocenu() {
  ocena++;

  //create textbox
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = "number";
  input.setAttribute("max",5);
  input.setAttribute("min",1);

  var myParent = document.body;

  //Create array of options to be added
  var array = ["Volvo","Saab","Mercades","Audi"];

  //Create and append select list
  var selectList = document.createElement('select');
  selectList.id = "mySelect";
  myParent.appendChild(selectList);

  //Create and append the options
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = array[i];
    option.text = array[i];
    selectList.appendChild(option);
  }   

  //create remove button
  var remove = document.createElement('button');
  remove.onclick = function(obrisiocenu) {
    removeElement(obrisiocenu);
  }
  remove.setAttribute("type", "dugme");
  remove.innerHTML = "-";
  
  var item = document.createElement('div')
  item.classList.add("item")
  
  item.appendChild(input);
  item.appendChild(selectList);
  item.appendChild(remove);
  
  stranica.appendChild(item)

}
```

```css
input[type="number"]{
    color : transparent;
    text-shadow : 0 0 0 #000;
}
input[type="number"]:focus{
    outline : none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="dugme1" onclick="javascript:dodajocenu();"> Add grade</button>
<br><br>
<div id="stranica">
</div>
```